# Micro Cloud Foundry Sinatra Hello world application fails to upload - JSON error

Tags: json, cloud-foundry

I'm just trying to get started with CloudFoundry and am attempting to upload the sample Hello World sinatra app. It fails with a JSON 413 error as follows:

*Would you like to deploy from the current directory? [Yn]: y

Pushing application 'hello'...

Creating Application: OK

Uploading Application:

 Checking for available resources: OK

Processing resources: OK

Packing application: OK

Uploading (1009M): OK

Error (JSON 413): 

413 Reques...*

I think this is something to do with the package being too large, the above output seems to suggest it's 1009M!?

Any thoughts on what might be going wrong here?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

There must be data in the same folder your app is located in since it's reporting a 1009MB payload. Try creating a new folder, moving the sinatra file there, and pushing to Cloud Foundry again.

Comment: Hi, OK thanks for the reply - I tried moving the file to a new, empty directory and uploaded from there. Still got the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Can you provide the app directory as a zipfile somewhere (dropbox) so I can download and try to reproduce the issue? What OS and VMC version are you using?